# Is the semigroup of lines $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, finitely generated

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, semigroups, finitely-generated

I was researching $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, the set of square $n\times n$ matrices with rational entries, as a semigroup with matrix multiplication. For $A,B\in\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, the equivalence relation $A\sim B$ will be true when $A=cB$ for $c\in\mathbb{Q}$, non-zero. The quotient, $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Q})/\sim$, is also a semigroup (looks like lines in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, when $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ is interpretted in Euclidean space).

I was wondering if this quotient semigroup is finitely generated (the set if finitely generated and one only has to hit a point on each line to generate it). I tried to prove by contradiction with finite generators and trying to find a non-generated element but to no avail.

Comment: I would guess it it finitely generated. We can write every matrix $A$ with rational coefficients as $$A=E_1\dots E_m diag(1, \dots 1, 0, \dots 0) F_1 \dots F_l$$ where $E_j, F_k$ correspond to row and column operations. So, we just need to ask ourselves whether we can finitely generate the column and row operation. I'd say without the quotient we cannot, but with the quotient there might be some hope.

Comment: Row switching and row adding are unproblematic, the question is whether we can finitely generate multiplication of a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the semigroup $S = \mathcal{M}_2(\mathbb{Q})/{\sim}$ is not finitely generated. Indeed, let $\cal A$ be a finite set of matrices and let $T$ be the semigroup generated by the matrices of the form $cA$, with $c \in {\Bbb Q}$ and $A \in {\cal A}$. Let us show that $T \not= {\cal M}_2({\Bbb Q})$. Consider the finite set $F$ of irreducible rational numbers equal to the determinant of some matrix in $\cal A$.
Let $P$ be the finite set of prime numbers dividing the numerator or the denominator of some element of $F$ and let $p$ be a prime number not in $P$.

I claim that the matrix $\pmatrix{p&0 \\ 0&1}$ is not in $T$. Otherwise, its determinant, which is equal to $p$, would be the determinant of a matrix of $T$, and hence of the form $c^2\frac{n}{m}$ where $p$ neither divides $n$ nor $m$. Writing $c$ as $\frac{a}{b}$, one would get $pb^2m = a^2n$, which is not possible.

Comment: In other words, there is a surjective monoid morphism $M_n(\mathbb{Q})\to \mathbb{Q}^\times\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}^{\mathbb{N}}$, which induces a surjective morphism $M_n(\mathbb{Q})/\sim \to (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\mathbb{N}}$, which is clearly not finitely generated.

Comment: @CaptainLama Could you elaborate, I am not sure to understand.

Comment: The way I wrote it is not quite right. Let us write $S=M_n(\mathbb{Q})/\sim$. You have the determinant morphism $(M_n(\mathbb{Q}),\cdot)\to (\mathbb{Q},\cdot)$, and since a scalar $c$ is sent to $c^n$, it induces a morphism $S\to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Q}^n$. Now $\mathbb{Q}=\{0\}\cup \mathbb{Q}^\times$, and the prime factor decomposition tells us that $\mathbb{Q}^\times\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$, where $\mathbb{Z}/2$ gives the sign, and $\mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ gives the $p$-adic valuations.

Comment: This means that we get a surjective monoid morphism $S\to \{0\}\cup (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$. Since $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ is not finitely generated, $S$ cannot be finitely generated either.

Comment: Your proof is just an explicit reformulation of that, saying that given a finite set $A\subset M_n(\mathbb{Q})$ you can always choose some prime $p$ which is not in the submonoid generated by the image of $A$ through this morphism.